# anyone can tell where is error in express that my hbs templete is not runing?

Tags: javascript, express

I have created a express code  rendering hbs but it is get rendering data Please help me to solve that error???  please help me regarding that help!! ..

```
     let express=require('express');
            let app=express();
            let path=require('path');
            app.set('veiw engine','hbs');
            let port =1000;
            app.ge1t('',(req,res)=>{
            res.render("index");
            })
            app.listen(1000,()=>{
                console.log(`listening to this port: ${port} `);
            })
    
    
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <title>Document</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p> hello </p>
                
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried their setup code here? https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-hbs

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem in your route url : app.ge1t('', should become: `app.get('/',`